# JS regular expressions for fisrt one letter and numbers

Tags: javascript, replace, redex

I try make regular expression for one letter Z and 12 digits.

`event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^Z{1}+(\d{12})]/, '');`

It is necessary for me that in the input field it was possible to enter one letter Z and then 12 digits only.

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you have `[]` in the regexp? `[]` is used for matching a character in a set, not for grouping.

Comment: I'm new to regular expressions... can you suggest your solution? For example, I have a solution for entering only numbers and it works. How can you do the same solution, but to enter one letter Z and then 12 digits?     event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^\d.]*/g, '');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp is

```
/^Z\d{12}$/
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `Z` matches the initial `Z`. There's no need for `{1}` since patterns always match exactly one time unless quantified.
- `\d{12}` matches exactly 12 digits
- `$` matches the end of the string

```js
const regex = /^Z\d{12}$/;

console.log(regex.test('Z123456789012')); // true
console.log(regex.test('X123456789012')); // false - begins with wrong letter
console.log(regex.test('Z1234567890')); // false - <12 digits
console.log(regex.test('Z123456A89012')); // false - letter mixed into digits
console.log(regex.test('Z123456789012345')); // false - >12 digits
```

Comment: This solution allows you to enter any letters and numbers in the input field...

Comment: No it doesn't. `Z` only matches `Z`.

Comment: I've added a code snippet showing that it doesn't match other things.

Comment: event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/^Z\d{12}$/, ''); - any letters...

Comment: Why are you using replace? If the input doesn't match, there's nothing to replace, so it stays the same.

Comment: I use field replacement when only numbers need to be entered and it works. But I need this replace for Z + 12 digits

Comment: `if (!event.target.value.match(/.../)) { event.target.value = ''; }`

Comment: For example, this code allows you to enter only the letter Z and numbers in the field.      event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^Z0-9]*/g, '');
 But I need to be able to enter the letters Z and 12 numbers. How to do it?

Comment: Remember that `replace()` REMOVES the match. So the pattern has to match what you DON'T want, not what you want to ALLOW.

Comment: This solution id working - ` event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/^[^Z\d]*(([Z]\d{0,12})?).*$/g, '$1');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251327/discussion-between-vlad-and-barmar).